The Dialog is not showing
I'm on Library Project. The new book button is for adding books, and when i try       adding another book, it duplicates. So I added     container.textContent = '';
on my display function to remove duplicates. I successfully added one book, but when i tried     adding another book, the modal doesn't show up anymore and I inspected in on edge. This is what it   says:

Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'showModal' on 'HTMLDialogElement': The element is not in a Document. at HTMLButtonElement.

(even though i have dialog.showModal(); and my dialog is present on html)
Here is my html and Javascript:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const container = document.querySelector('.container')
  const Btn = document.querySelector('#mybtn');
  const dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
  const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');

  const myLibrary = [];

  function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;

    this.info = function() {
      return `Title: ${this.title}
                   Author: ${this.author}
                   Pages: ${this.pages}  
                   Read: ${this.read}`;
    }
  }

  function addBookToLibrary() {
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
    const read = document.querySelector('input[name="read"]:checked').value;
    const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read);

    myLibrary.push(newBook)
  }

  /*
  let addAnother = true;

  while(addAnother){
      addBookToLibrary()
      addAnother = prompt("Would you like to add another book? ") == 'yes';
  }*/

  function display() {
    container.textContent = '';

    myLibrary.forEach(lib => {
      const book = document.createElement('div');
      book.classList.add('book');
      const newP = document.createElement('p');

      book.appendChild(newP);
      container.appendChild(book);

      newP.textContent = lib.info();
    })

  }

  Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dialog.showModal();
  });

  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    addBookToLibrary();
    display();
    event.preventDefault();
    dialog.close();
  });

});
<dialog id='dialog'>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
      <label for="author">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
      <label for="pages">Pages</label>
      <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages">
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
      <legend>Have you read it?</legend>
      <div class='yes'>
        <input type="radio" id="read" name="read" value="read">
        <label for="read">Yes</label>
      </div>
      <div class='no'>
        <input type="radio" id="not_read" name="read" value="not_read">
        <label for="not_read">No</label>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
    <div class='btn_submit'>
      <button id='submit' type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>



I'd appreciate answers, thank you.

We need a proper [mre] from you. Right now, we can't even see half the HTML elements this tries to access. But it sounds pretty much like you're removing your modal from the DOM, by removing the content of that container.

Check your console as well to know your errors

@UdanJayanith Put triple-backticks around a code block that contains embedded backticks.

What's the difference between your definition and the original? If you're going to recommend improving it, probably modern class syntax would be best.

@Mehdi The error message is in the question. It's easier to see now that I reformatted the question.

i have never seen a js function written like that. try using this book function
    return  `Title: ${title}
             Author: ${author}
             Pages: ${pages}  
             Read: ${read}`
} ``` and change newBook variable in addBookToLibrary function to this                    ```const newBook = Book(title, author, pages, read)```

@Barmar you are correct, did not see it . Actualy now it is more clear and visible. Thanks
